# запрос из двух таблиц - в результат из второй таблицы добавить в столбцы

Tags: mysql, sql

помогите разобраться, не пойму как запрос составить

пример - две таблицы такой структуры

1. заявки - order

id name price

```
1  order1 1000
2  order2 2000
```

2. доп поля заявки - attrib - то есть, может быть разное количество полей для заказа

id order_id attrib_id attrib_name attrib_value

```
id  order_id  attrib_id  attrib_name  attrib_value
1  1          101        цвет         красный
2  1          102        размер       100
3  1          103        дата         30-10-2023
4  2          101        цвет         зеленый
5  2          102        размер       300
```

как сделать запрос, чтобы результат был вида:

```
order.id order.price   цвет       размер  дата
1          1000        красный    100     30-10-2023
2          2000        зеленый    300     null
```

Comment: при известном фиксированном наборе параметров решается через PIVOT. При произвольном наборе атрибутов динамический SQL.